# How to show the raster image from an GeoTIFF

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, vector

I have a TIFF file:  http://files.sweetysoft.com/image_after_2021_05_19/3653/China_2020_1km_UNadj.tif

When open it with windows image viewer, it only shows China Map like this:

[image]

When open it with ArcMap, I can see the "raster" stuff like this:

[image]

What is the name of the blue circle area?

Comment: Please restrict yourself to one question per post. Also, your first question isn't clear. You have raster data, which is an image containing pixels which represent data values.

Comment: OK, second question removed.

Comment: So the blue circle content is controlled/shown by the raster data ?

Comment: Everything within the blue circle IS raster data. Also, everything outside. Raster data contains pixels of a fixed size, while vector data is composed of nodes, which may form single points, lines or polygons.

Comment: The pixels have different values which windows image viewer doesnt show, but ArcMap does. You can click the raster with the i-tool and see the values.

Comment: thanks @Erik, you answered my question. you can copy the `comment` as `answer` then I can mark it as accept.

Comment: @BERA Yes, I know this.  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your geotiff is a single band raster with 32bit floating point values and has the following statistics:

```
Minimum=0.000, Maximum=365317.750, Mean=150.151, StdDev=1054.022
```

Windows image viewer doesn't know how to display this data (non-RGB with values > 255), whereas ArcMap knows how to scale the values for display and can even apply a colour ramp.

Comment: great, so how do to get the statistics ( Minimum = 0.000, Max = ... ) ?   Do you read it via ArcMap ?

Comment: It depends on the software you want to use. I used something called gdal, but you can use ArcMap

Comment: got it, thank a lot!